# "Unexpected element" error while uploading a WSDL file in SoapUI

Tags: xml, web-services, wsdl, jmeter, gsoap

I have tested successfully the example of **The WS-Addressing Plug-in**. The client and server can exchange data successfully.
I have generated the WSDL file using this command :

```
soapcpp2 -a -Igsoap_dir wsademo.h
```

However, when I try to create make some test by SoapUI, I get an error in parsing the file :

```
Error loading [http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/02/duplex]:
org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlException: error: Unexpected element: CDATA
```

I don't understand the problem. Can anybody help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a problem with the input XML.
Check your input XML for incorrect elements.

Hope this will help.